# Panda module export, split data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to read a .txt file and output the count of each letter which works, however, I'm having trouble exporting that data to .csv in a specific way.

A snippet of the code:

```
freqs = {}
with open(Book1) as f:
    for line in f:
        for char in line:
            if char in freqs:
                freqs[char] += 1
            else:
                freqs[char] = 1

print(freqs)
```

And for the exporting to csv, I did the following:

```
test = {'Book 1 Output':[freqs]}

df = pd.DataFrame(test, columns=['Book 1 Output'])

df.to_csv(r'book_export.csv', sep=',')
```

Currently when I run it, the export looks like this (Manually done):

[image]

However I want the output to be each individual row, so it should look something like this when I open it: [image]

I want it to separate it from the ":" and "," into 3 different columns.

I've tried various other answers on here but most of them end up with giving `ValueErrors` so maybe I just don't know how to apply it like the following one.

```
df[[',']] = df[','].str.split(expand=True)
```

Comment: can you add the ```freqs``` variable in ```test = {'Book 1 Output':[freqs]}```

Comment: The freqs variable is just user-inputted random letters/words, I'll add it in.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.from_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) with [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) for set index name, then csv looks like you need:

```
#sample data
freqs = {'a':5,'b':2}


df = (pd.DataFrame.from_dict(freqs, orient='index',columns=['Book 1 Output'])
        .rename_axis('Letter'))
print (df)
        Book 1 Output
Letter               
a                   5
b                   2

df.to_csv(r'book_export.csv', sep=',')
```

Or alternative is use `Series`:

```
s = pd.Series(freqs, name='Book 1 Output').rename_axis('Letter')
print (s)
Letter
a    5
b    2
Name: Book 1 Output, dtype: int64

s.to_csv(r'book_export.csv', sep=',')
```

EDIT:

If there are multiple frequencies change `DataFrame` constructor:

```
freqs = {'a':5,'b':2}
freqs1 = {'a':9,'b':3}

df = pd.DataFrame({'f1':freqs, 'f2':freqs1}).rename_axis('Letter')
print (df)
        f1  f2
Letter        
a        5   9
b        2   3
```

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly. I'm just curious but if I had more than 1 variable, so let's say freq and freq2, how would that work? I've tried editing the DataFrame.from_dict but it gave me a tuple error 'AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'to_csv''